# Is there a way to install Unity or Gnome Shell along with Lubuntu?

Tags: unity, gnome, lubuntu

I'm using Lubuntu for a while now, but found a couple of details that I wanted to view with Unity (that's another story).

Ok, the thing is: I've tried on a VM with Lubuntu to install Unity (`sudo apt-get install unity`) When the installation is over. I selected in the Lubuntu login Unity/Unity2D but did not work.

Right now I'm installing `ubuntu-desktop`, I am presuming that will work, but also it will change my login for example.

Is there a way to do a "clean" installation of Unity but not make major changes on my Lubuntu?

I would prefer Gnome-Shell instead of Unity.

Comment: Unity is build on the top of gnome3

Comment: In essence, you have to accept the changes if you want to get a proper working Unity or Gnome Shell. They have dependencies.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To install unity, run the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

To install gnome-shell, do the same in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell
```

You can choose the default login manager as per your preference.

Comment: Would there be a performance hit in doing so?

Comment: @Alex: it will not affect perfomence of default DE, but gnome-shell is slower than lxde(default de of lubuntu)

Comment: How do you choose the login manager? I'm using Lubuntu to run a very old machine, but if I have to go much longer without the Unity panel, I'm going to explode. Other than the unity panel, I want all the other things to be the default lightweight Lubuntu things: the login screen, etc. Is the Unity panel incompatible with LXDE?

Comment: If you are using 12.04 , you can use unity 2D panel in lubuntu. Unity-3D panel is not compatable with lxde

Comment: JamesTheAwesomeDude:  Just check this screencast about add a second panel like unity panel but on lubuntu: http://blip.tv/ubuntu-switcher/lubuntu-screencast-lxpanel-2-panel-configuration-5316669

Answer (score 2):

It is very easy to install Gnome-shell in Lubuntu 12.10.

Open Synaptic Package Manager, reload it, search for Gnome-shell and install it. There is **no need** to install Ubuntu-desktop.

You can also agree to install GDM, which would give you a nice log in screen.

Restart and log into Gnome.

I am writing from Lubuntu + Gnome shell. No crashes.