# Does the HUD work in Lubuntu?

Tags: unity, lubuntu, hud

I have a Lubuntu install, and have noticed that the HUD that goes along with something called Unity does not appear when I tap alt.  I learned about the HUD from the notes about the most recent Ubuntu patch, which I think was "Precise Pangolin".

That page has a small section about the HUD, but I couldn't find any links to talk about it more in depth.  The patch notes indicated that it should have been installed automatically, and I was wondering if there are any known reasons it might not be working.  I have looked through the existing questions and could not find a similar question.

My only thought were that I run Lubuntu, and that I have no idea what Unity is.  Please advise.

Comment: which version of lubuntu?

Answer (score 4):

HUD is currently available for unity only ,if you are using Lubuntu 12.04 you can enjoy features of HUD by installing unity inside Lubuntu

**Linked questions**

1. [Is there a way to install Unity or Gnome Shell along with Lubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/110516/is-there-a-way-to-install-unity-or-gnome-shell-along-with-lubuntu/110536#110536)
2. [What is the Unity HUD and how can I install it on my system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/98132/what-is-the-unity-hud-and-how-can-i-install-it-on-my-system)
3. [How do I use the HUD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131617/how-do-i-use-the-hud)

Comment: Basically what I said, except you actually had links to back it up. :) Good info I'm not this person!

Answer (score 1):

Lubuntu uses the LXDE desktop environment. Ubuntu (The standard Ubuntu) uses what is called the Unity shell. There are a few different -buntu operating systems, such as Kubuntu, which uses the KDE environment, or Xubuntu, which uses the XFCE environment.

The HUD is exclusive to only the Unity shell. However, you can run this shell on Lubuntu by installing the shell. My personal bit of advice would be to download Ubuntu (standard Ubuntu, that is) and install it. However, if you would prefer having both the LXDE environment and the Unity shell, you can install Unity. If you would like to install it, there are plenty of guides here on AU.

I have only used Ubuntu, and it came preinstalled with Unity, so I cannot tell you how exactly to install the Unity shell.

Comment: Entering `sudo apt-get install unity` into a terminal will install Unity.