# I am trying to get GNOME desktop on lubuntu, but im not sure what do to from here

Tags: gnome, lubuntu

I'm trying to install the GNOME Desktop on Lubuntu, I did all the steps, but it always takes me here:

[image: apt-get install output]

I'm confused.

I need help getting it.

Comment: Silly question, but why not replace Lubuntu with stock Ubuntu? This would give you what you need, though it would require that you re-download your software and restore a backup of your important files ...

Comment: The `gnome-shell` package is only one piece of the Gnome desktop. It's unclear what "all the steps" you followed are. A link to those steps would be rather helpful so we can understand what you did.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/110516/is-there-a-way-to-install-unity-or-gnome-shell-along-with-lubuntu?newreg=0d0fa5200c844cb4979b14578a6eaf00

Answer (score 4):

Start by installing the desktop with:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

Insert your password and press Y when asked. That'll take a few minutes When you're done, reboot your computer.

At the login screen, look up at the top where it says 'Session' and use that drop down menu to select the newly installed Ubuntu desktop. It will look similar to this, though probably at a different resolution. (I did this in VirtualBox.)

[image: Pick Ubuntu]

Then, enter your password and login. It should look like this:

[image: See? It works.]